# get list of all users SharePoint using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have the id of the user and I need to get his login name.
I use REST API: there is my code :

```
function ReturnItemBY(fieldName, listname, id, url) {
    //Url should be _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
    // var item = getListItems(url, listName, customquery, '', '');
    //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Start, "sp.js");
    var item = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + id + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            //alert(data);
            item = data.d;
        },
        async: false
    });
    return item.fieldName;


}
```

the problem is that he didnt know the name of the list which I put it "Users".

Dose any one know how can get it ,best regards.

Comment: You ask how to get users, yet your example code is about getting items. I'm not sure if I should show you how to get user in a field (with `$expand`) or how to get a user by id (from `/Users`). Sorry, but your question makes no sense to me

Comment: For me as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this link: [Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432(v=office.15).aspx). As noted by the comments from @eirikb and @Vadim, the url you are using will never give anything close to a list users.

Answer (score 17):

I know this question was asked long ago but it might help someone in the future.

If you want to get all the users in your Sharepoint site you can use :

```
/_api/web/siteusers?
```

If you want to get the properties of the current user on the site then you can use :

```
/_api/web/currentUser?
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is good thanks. I was able to get the Id of someone with this code _api/web/siteUsers?$select=Id,LoginName,Title,Email&$filter=Title eq 'FirstName SecondName'

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, that really helped.